# Como pegar o valor de um formulário específico da página anterior em PHP?

Tags: php, html

Boa tarde!

Uma página em PHP contém dois formulários `form`, cada um com um `submit`. Como obter os dados do `form` 1, por exemplo, depois de apertar o submit através do POST? Normalmente quando havia só um formulário ele pegava os dados diretamente através do código abaixo: (sendo que CNPJ era o id de um `input` do formulário):

```css
table {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="localizacao" name="localizacao" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit=" return false;">
  <table width="50%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <div align="center"><img src=img/logo.jpg></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top">
        <h2>Pesquisa</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="156">Selecione o STATUS:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="status" id="status">
          <option value="0">Recebido</option>
          <option value="1">Em trânsito</option>
          <option value="2">Encerrado</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CNPJ:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="CNPJ" type="text" id="CNPJ" size="20" maxlength="14" />
        <span class="style1">*</span> <span class="style3">somente n&uacute;meros</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        VIAGEM:
      </td>
      <td width="835"><input name="VIAGEM" type="text" id="VIAGEM" size="20" maxlength="14" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <input name="pesquisar" type="submit" id="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar" />
          <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar!" />
          <br />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="alteracoes" name="alteracoes" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return validaCampoAltera(); return false;">
  <table width="50%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top">
        <h2>Modifica</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">VIAGEM:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="VIAGEM" type="text" id="VIAGEM" size="20" maxlength="14" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">NOVO STATUS:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="NVSTATUS" type="text" id="NVSTATUS" size="1" maxlength="1" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">EMBARCACAO:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="EMBARC" type="text" id="EMBARC" size="20" maxlength="10" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATSAI" type="text" id="DATSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA SAIDA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORSAI" type="text" id="HORSAI" size="20" maxlength="10" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">DATA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="DATCH" type="text" id="DATCH" size="20" maxlength="10" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">HORA CHEGADA:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="HORCHE" type="text" id="HORCHE" size="20" maxlength="10" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <input name="atualizar" type="submit" id="atualizar" value="ATUALIZAR" />
          <br />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

`if (isset($_POST["CNPJ"])){
        $CNPJ = $_POST ["CNPJ"];
    }`

Comment: Por favor incluir mais informações e detalhar melhor

Comment: Se são dois formulários, eles serão submetidos de forma individual: ou submete o primeiro, ou o segundo. Submeter um não envia os dados do outro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, como fazer com que ele pegue os dados do `formulario1`, por exemplo? Seria algo como `$CNPJ = $_POST ["formulario1.CNPJ"]`?

Comment: Como é o seu código HTML? Qual formulário está submetendo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, pergunta editada com o código em HTML.

Comment: @Marvin você só terá acesso aos dados do formulário submetido, se não submeter o primeiro você não vai ter acesso ao dados dele.

Comment: Apenas podias usar um botão para submeter os dois formulário ao mesmo tempo, senão penso que não exista forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi tirar o espaço que havia em `onsubmit` e colocar `true`.

```
onsubmit=" return false;"
```

para

```
onsubmit="return true;"
```

em

```html
<form id="localizacao" name="localizacao" method="post" action="rastreamento.php" onsubmit="return true;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada formulário da página, independente de quantos sejam, é submetido individualmente. Logo, se você tiver dois formulários e cada um tiver o seu submit, somente o formulário no qual o submit foi acionado terá os dados enviados pro servidor, lembrando que cada form deve ter seu submit. No seu caso, se você clicar no submit do formulário "localizacao", só os inputs dele serão enviado via post, mesmo havendo inputs no outro formulário com o mesmo nome. Isso também deve ser tratado no seu back-end, já que ambos os formulários enviam para o mesmo arquivo, seu código deve saber comparar, filtrar e tratar a captação dos dados de acordo acordo ao formulário de origem dos mesmos.